# Replicar alterações em servidores

Tags: linux, servidor, magento, cliente-servidor, servidor-de-aplicação

Boa tarde pessoal.

Trabalho com Magento um sistema feito em PHP. 
Eu possuo a mesma aplicação em vários servidores com apenas o tema tendo diferença. O problema é quando quero desenvolver um módulo, ou apenas algumas modificações tenho que entrar em todos os server e repassar as alterações. Já procurei algumas ferramentas para automatizar esta tarefa, mas não suprem minha necessidade. Gostaria de saber se alguém de vocês enfrentaram o mesmo problema. Quais ferramentas vocês utilizam?

DETALHE: As aplicações estão em servidores Linux.

Comment: Conhece o Git? Pelo que entendi do seu problema, poderia usar o git para 'sincronizar' as atualizações nos diversos locais.

Comment: espreita também o `rsync`